# String comparison with different COLLATION

Tags: php, mysql, sql, compare, collation

**MYSQL databases**

**Database1 - table - table1**
**id** - int
**title** - **utf8_general_ci** 
values - 
1, Bienvenue Chez les Châ€™tis
2, ABC
3, XYZ

**Database2 - table - table2**
id - int 
title - **utf8_unicode_ci**  
values - 
1, Bienvenue Chez les Ch’tis 
2, ABC 
3, QWE

I have list of titles in both the tables as above.I want to list titles which are not same.

I tries so many different things but no luck.

How can I compare these titles?

```
SELECT database1.table1.title as title1,database2.table2.title as title2 
FROM database1.table1 JOIN database2.table2 ON (database1.table1.id =database2.table2)
WHERE database1.table1.title NOT LIKE database2.table2.title COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

result from above query:
Bienvenue Chez les Châ€™tis, Bienvenue Chez les Ch’tis 
XYZ, QWE

But I just want below in result
 
XYZ, QWE

I want to exclude french one, I want to consider it as a identical titles.

Comment: can you change db1 to  utf8_unicode_ci ?

Comment: Those characters look malformed. Both collations you mentioned are unicode so that shouldn't happen. I don't think its a collation issue.

Comment: The collation specifies both character encoding and sorting.  You only need to be concerned about the character encoding, and these are the same.  The two titles you show *are* different, though that difference may be a data error.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. I will look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`â€™` is Mojibake for `’`.  The problem came when storing the *same* right-single-quote in two different ways.  Not a `COLLATION` issue.

First, check the two tables to see what got stored:

```
SELECT HEX(title) FROM database1.table1 WHERE id = 1
```

Two likely cases of what you will find are these:

```
C  h          ...        t  i  s
43 68        E28099      74 69 73  -- correctly encoded with UTF-8
43 68 C3A2 E282AC E284A2 74 69 73  -- "double encoded"
```

(I added spacing to the HEX for clarity.)

If one of the tables is "doubly encoded", then it got messed up during `INSERTing`.  The strings will *not* compare equal.

[*This Q&A*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) discusses things further.  Then see [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases) for fixing the doubly encoded text.  But be sure to apply it only to the broken data.